# How can I shorten this regex for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, optimization

Basically I just want it to match *anything* inside `()`. I tried the `.` and `*` but they don't seem to work. Right now my regex looks like:

```
\(([\\\[\]\-\d\w\s/*\.])+\)
```

The strings it's going to match are URL routes like:

```
#!/foo/bar/([a-z])/([\d\w])/(*)
```

In this example, my regex above matches:

- `([a-z])`
- `([\d\w])`
- `(*)`

  <strike>BONUS:
  How can I make it so that it only matches when it starts with a `(` and ends with a `)`. I thought I used the `^` at the front where it's `\(` and the `$` and the end where it's `\)` but no luck.</strike>
  Disregard this bonus. I didnt realize it didnt matter...

Answer (score 3):

> Basically I just want it to match *anything* inside `()`.
> BONUS: How can I make it so that it only matches when it starts with a `(` and ends with a `)`?

Easy peasy.

```
var re1 = /^\(.*\)$/
// or
var re2 = new RegExp('^\\(.*\\)$');
```

---

#### Edit

Re: [@Mike Samuel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20394/mike-samuel) comments

> Does not match newlines between the parentheses which were explicitly matched by \s in the original.
> ...
> Maybe you should use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`
> ...
> If you're going to exclude newlines you should do so intentionally or explicitly.

Note that `.` matches any single character except the newline character. If you also want to match newlines as part of the "anything" between parentheses, use the `[\s\S]` character class:

```
var re3 = /^\([\s\S]*\)$/
// or
var re4 = new RegExp('^\\([\\s\\S]*\\)$');
```

Comment: Does not match newlines between the parentheses which were explicitly matched by `\s` in the original.

Comment: `m` affects the behavior of `^` and `$`, not `.`.  You're thinking of `s` which is in perl but not JavaScript.  Maybe you should use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`.

Comment: Yes, I always forget exactly what `m` does (and it's rarely what I want) so I reverted. Since when are newlines needed in URL routes?

Comment: @Matt If you're going to exclude newlines you should do so intentionally or explicitly.  A comment or caveat explaining that newlines are excluded but not other characters allowed in URLS would be perfectly adequate.  Otherwise people reading this will get the impression that you are solving the "anything" asked for in the OP.

Comment: @Matt.  Lovely.  `[\s\S]` in `re4` should be `[\\s\\S]`.  On a nitpicky note, `.` excludes multiple newline characters ; it's equivalent to `[^\r\n\u2028\u2029]`.

Comment: Gah! Nice catch... as for the nitpick, I was quoting [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions) verbatim - you are right again though!

Comment: The other solutions are better.

Comment: Maybe im doing it wrong, but: http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%2F^%5C(%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%5C)%24%2F&input=%23!%2Ffoo%2Fbar%2F(%5Ba-z%5D)%2F(%5B%5Cd%5Cw%5D)%2F(*) doesnt seem to match nor does my quick test on http://jsbin.com/ivola4/edit :(

Comment: With this URL #!/foo/bar/([a-z])/([\d\w])/(*)

Comment: @Oscar the regexes I provided **only match strings that start with `(` and end with `)`.** This has nothing to do with the URL route you mentioned. If you want a regex that matches a URL, it would be helpful if you could clarify exactly what should and shouldn't be matched.

Comment: Sorry, in my OP i was trying to get at i want to match the `()`. and I want to start searching at the start of a `(` and end at a `)`. My URL in my OP would have three matches.

Comment: Everything should be matched, its up the the developer (im writing a library). Part of my script simply returns the matches in the URL. i.e. if i go to foo/bar/1 and I did, in my route, foo/bar/(\d) it'd return `1` to me so I can do something with it... i hope that helps more?

Comment: Oh, and, yeah, newlines dont need to be matched... obv.

Comment: @Oscar sorry, I don't understand. You said "everything should be matched" which does not clarify what you are trying for. I understand that everything _between parentheses_ should be matched, but what's the bigger context? What do parentheses have to do with URL routes?

Comment: See my 2nd comment to your last comment. In short, its a way for a developer to grab a piece of a URL when a user goes to it. i.e. im at foo/bar and i go to /foo/bar/1 and i have `foo/bar/(\d)` in my route, the developer gets a callback with an array of matches, in this case 1 match and thatd be `1`

Comment: So you want a regex that will capture `'\d'` in the string `'foo/bar/(\d)'`?

Comment: well, anything inside of the `()`. Im going to take the matches in the current URL when a user goes to a URL and then ill spit back a nice array to the developer in a callback like `.register('/foo/bar/(\d)',function(data,urlMatches){ alert('Hello user with the id of'+urlMatches[0]) })` Does that make more sense?

Comment: ill use the regex they give me to match the current url. The developer wont know what the URL is or WHEN the user hits the URL. my script does that. But when it does it triggers a callback

Comment: I _think_ I get what you want now. Given some URL pattern, you want to be able to match patterns inside of paren pairs, such as `'\d'` in `'foo/bar/(\d)'` or `'[a-z]'`, `'[\d\w]'`, and `'*'` in `'/foo/bar/([a-z])/([\d\w])/(*)'` - is that right? If so, what does this have to do with the "bonus" you mentioned (_"How can I make it so that it only matches when it starts with a ( and ends with a )?"_)?

Comment: Well, i guess i just thought that if i dont explicitly say ( is the start and ) is the end, then there might be cases where it wont match correctly for whatever reason. I was just trying to be very explicit is all :\

Answer (score 3):

To negate a match, you use the `[^...]` construct. Thus, to match anything within parentheses, you would use:

```
\([^)]+\)
```

which says "match any string that starts with an open parenthesis, contains any number of characters that are **not** closing parentheses and ends with a closing parenthesis.

To match entire lines that match the above construct, just wrap it with `^` and `$`:

```
^\([^)]+\)$
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you worried about nested parentheses? If not, you could set it up to match all characters that aren't a closing paren:

```
\(([^)]*)\)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you're doing, but try this:

```
var re = /\/(\([^()]+\)(?=\/|$)/;
```

Matching the leading slash in addition to the opening paren ensures that the paren is indeed at the beginning.  You can't do the same thing at the end because you don't know there will *be* a trailing slash.  And if there is one, you don't want to consume it because it's also the *leading* slash for the next match attempt.

Instead, you use the lookahead - `(?=\/|$)` - to match the trailing slash without consuming it.  If there is no slash, I assume no other character should be present either--hence the anchor: `$`.

@patorjk brought up a good point, though: can there be more parentheses between the outermost pair?  If there are, the problem is much more complicated.  I won't bother trying to expand my regex to deal with nested parens; some regex flavors can handle such things, but not JavaScript.  Instead I'll recommend this sloppier regex:

```
\/(\([\s\S]+?\))(?=\/|$)
```

I say "sloppy" because it relies on the assumption that the sequences `/(` and `)/` will never appear inside a valid match.  As with my first regex, the text that you're interested in (i.e., everything but the leading and trailing slashes) will be captured in group #1.

Notice the non-greedy quantifier, too.  With a regular greedy quantifier it will match everything from the first `(` to the last `)` in one shot.  In other words, it'll match `([a-z])/([\d\w])/(*)` instead of `([a-z])`, `([\d\w])` and `(*)` as you wanted.